# How to use np.random.seed() to create new matrix with fixed random value

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to create new matrix (V) with fixed random value in each position (every time I run algorithm, I want to have this same matrix showing up). Is it possible to use np.random.seed() for matrix? Something like

```
V = np.zeros([20,50])
V = np.random.seed(V)
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you mean by "new matrix with consistently random value each time".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this to set the seed:

```
np.random.seed(0) # or whatever value you fancy
```

and then generate your random data:

```
V = np.random.rand(your_shape) # or whatever randomness you fancy like randint, randn ...
```

Comment: I tried this and found the number in parenthesis of `np.random.seed(0)` represent the version of randomness? May I ask why this number is important? I mean when I write new `np.random.seed()`, I think all the version is re-created. Is the number can be reused or something later on?

Comment: @Jan: The argument is entirely upto you, but you can rest assured that that number will guarantee consistency across any implementation.

Comment: @Jan, `np.random.seed()` will reset the seed (thus the state) of your (pseudo-)random number generator but in an uncontrolled way (typically from the current time, this is used when you want to ensure each run will give different results). Specifying the seed with `np.random.seed(1234)` or equivalent is what you need to ensure repeatability.